# How to remove a bit from an int?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    private enum Wall
    {
        Up = 0x0001,
        Down = 0x0010,
        Left = 0x0100,
        Right = 0x1000,
    }

private void Test()
{
    int walls = 0x1111;
    var wallsWithRightWallRemoved = walls | Wall.Right;
    // wallsWithRightWallRemoved  should now be this: 0x0111    
}
```

I have a variable called walls where the 0x1111 represents 4 booleans basically. From the walls I want to remove the right wall so I substract it from it (walls | Wall.Right;) , but I am getting "Cannot apply operator & to operands of type int".
Basically I want to end up with a variable which contains 0x0111.

Thank you

Comment: `|` is bit-wise OR, not subtraction. You're *adding* the right wall, not removing it.

Comment: I think part of your error is your enum is missing `[Flags]`

Comment: @Scott [`[Flags]` doesn't alter an enum's implementation, it's for display purposes only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c). :)

Comment: @Askerman _"a strange int related error"_ isn't answerable. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, but it still says "Cannot apply operator & to operands of type int" even with Flags added

Comment: `walls & (int) ~ Wall.Right`

Comment: What is the ~ for? But why do it need to cast it when the enum is already an int?

Comment: @Askerman it can be *cast* to an `int`, but it isn't an `int`. `int right = Wall.Right` wouldn't compile, for example; you need to cast it. `~` is the bitwise complement operator, it flips the bits so you're AND-ing `0111` which will unset the fourth bit.

Comment: You're looking for the logical XNOR operation, also knows as logical biconditional. It's achieved in C# as follows: `wallsWithRightWallRemoved = ~(walls ^ Wall.Right)` Also you would need to use the `[Flags] ` attribute on your enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wallsWithRightWallRemoved = walls & 0x0111;
```

Or will set bits that are in either.  And will unset bits that are 0 in either, which is what you want to do.